# How do I get a TextView to the center of the bottom?

Tags: java, android, textview

You can get the TextView to Bottom, Center, Center Horizontal and others, but so far I didn't find out how to get it to the center of the bottom if it is even possible.

This is the code for my button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="99dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/sq_donate" />
```

Is it possible to do it?

**EDIT, whole layout here:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tominocz.stonequestapp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame,ContentDescription,HardcodedText,SpUsage,TextViewEdits,Deprecated,SmallSp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/sq_bg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/sq_donate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="236dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:editable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="sdf"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="238dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/sq_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="171dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:editable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="s"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#528A50"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What is button's parent layout ?

Comment: it stretches the image to the sides

Comment: Remove _android:layout_gravity_ and replace with _android:gravity="center | bottom"_

Comment: @Rick I know, but that doesn't work

Comment: Can you post the entire layout?

Comment: `<RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce now how do I use it?

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: If its in a relative layout, you can use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to get the button to align with the bottom and android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" to get it to the center. Seeing the layout would be helpful

Comment: Somebody just answered and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add another parameter

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

Comment: I just realized.. bottom and the center couldn't really work together :D
Thanks!